# How to create a hard link to an existing file or directory in C?

Tags: c, hardlink

I am looking to create a hard link to a file or directory that already exists. For instance a user chooses to create a hard link to a file named "pathname" and the user can choose the name of the link file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow.. use libc function `link` [14.4 Hard Links](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hard-Links.html)

Comment: @ThiruShetty make that an answer?

Comment: @immibis yes, it's one of the way to achieve and its standard libc call.

Answer (score 1):

On most modern versions of Unix (or variants of Unix), you cannot create a hard link to a directory.  POSIX allows it if you have sufficient privileges and the system supports it, but some (I believe most) systems do not allow it.

To create a hard link, you need to use the [`link()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html) function (system call):

```
if (link(existing_file, new_name) != 0)
    …link failed…
```

Note that the new name must be complete, unlike the `ln` command.  You cannot specify a directory as the new name; you must specify the file name within the directory.

---

> Can you be a bit more specific about how the `link()` function works?

If invoked as `link(source, target)`, then a file of some sort must exist with the name in `source` (it can't be a directory unless perhaps you have 'appropriate privileges' — which means superuser or `root` privileges), and there must not be a file with the name in `target`, but all the directories leading to the file named by `target` must exist.  Assuming the preconditions are met, after the system call is successful, then you can refer to the same file contents by either the name in `source` or the name in `target`.

> For instance if I ask a user to choose an existing path and then choose a name for the hard link being created, how would I go about this?

FWIW, don't bother with prompting — use command line arguments, like the [`ln`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html) command does.

> I also read that I have to unlink the original file.

You probably don't, but that depends on the semantics of what you want to achieve, and what you mean by 'original file'.  It would be possible to write code that removes the target file if it already exists (like `ln -f source target` would remove the target file if it already exists).  It would be possible to write code that removes the source file name after the link is successful (like `mv source target` — note the different command name).  It would be possible to write code that attempts to ensure that all the directories leading to the target are created if they don't already exist (like `mkdir -p $(dirname target)`).  Etc.  You could decide to allow a target directory to be specified by a command line option, instead of just using the last argument as the target directory.  Etc.  There are lots of possibilities — you just have to decide what semantics you want and implement them.  Note that the rules for symbolic (soft) links and the [`symlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/symlink.html) function are different from the rules for hard links.

Here's some code (source file `link37.c`):

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    if (argc != 3)
        err_usage("source target");
    char *source = argv[1];
    char *target = argv[2];
    struct stat sb;
    if (stat(source, &sb) != 0)
        err_syserr("cannot access source file '%s': ", source);
    if (stat(target, &sb) == 0)
    {
        if (!S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
            err_error("name '%s' exists and is not a directory\n", target);
        else
        {
            char *slash = strrchr(source, '/');
            if (slash == 0)
                slash = source;
            else
                slash++;
            if (*slash == '\0')
                err_error("name '%s' cannot end with a slash\n", source);
            size_t baselen = strlen(target);
            size_t filelen = strlen(slash);
            size_t namelen = baselen + filelen + 2;
            char *name = malloc(namelen);
            if (name == 0)
                err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes memory: ", namelen);
            memmove(name, target, baselen);
            memmove(name + baselen, "/", 1);
            memmove(name + baselen + 1, slash, filelen + 1);
            target = name;
        }
    }
    if (link(source, target) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to link '%s' to '%s': ", source, target);
    if (target != argv[2])
        free(target);
    return 0;
}
```

The `free()` at the end is not really necessary.  The functions starting `err_` are available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  They're how I report errors in programs.  Some systems have a header `<err.h>` and a motley assortment of functions that do some of what my package does — have fun with them (I don't like them, but there's a strong case of NIH syndrome too).  There are other ways to concatenate the file name components; one would be to use `sprintf(name, "%s/%s", target, slash)` instead of 3 `memmove()` operations.

Sample run:

```
$ link37 link37.c chameleon
$ mkdir -p doc
$ link37 link37.c doc
$ link37 /Users/jonathanleffler/soq/ src
link37: name '/Users/jonathanleffler/soq/' cannot end with a slash
$ link37 /Users/jonathanleffler/soq src
link37: failed to link '/Users/jonathanleffler/soq' to 'src/soq': error (1) Operation not permitted
$ link37 link37.c chameleon
link37: name 'chameleon' exists and is not a directory
$ link37 /no/where/file.c /some/where/
link37: cannot access source file '/no/where/file.c': error (2) No such file or directory
$ link37 link37.c /some/where/
link37: failed to link 'link37.c' to '/some/where/': error (2) No such file or directory
$ rm -f doc/link37.c chameleon
$ rmdir doc 2>/dev/null
$
```

I had a directory `doc` already in existence (so the `mkdir -p doc` didn't do anything), but the `rmdir doc` at the end did no damage either. That's why I didn't use `rm -fr doc` though — I have information I want to keep in `doc`.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how the link() function works? For instance if I ask a user to choose an existing path and then choose a name for the hard link being created, how would I go about this? I also read that I have to unlink the original file. I am just having issues understanding this. Thank you!

Comment: See the extensive extra information in the updated answer.